# how to replace strings in json response and send it jmeter

Tags: json, regex, jmeter, beanshell

What's the best way to replace strings in JSON response? In my case, I need to extract response with regex. Extracted value is saved as savedItems and within that saved items, I need to search for below strings and replace then post it again. In 2 requests, first request to get then post with 2nd request (strings replaced).

I'm trying to use BellShell PostProcessor within the regex extractor and trying to replace but it doesn't seems to work.

```
Original string: rate":10.370681}
Replace with this: rate":10.370681,"$rowSelect":false,"$rowState":"invalid":false,"dirty":false,"added":false}
```

There are possibly 100 - 500 to be replaced so any recommendation? I'm still new to beanshell and tried it with below codes but no luck yet :)

```
debug();

try {
String savedItems = vars.get("Saved_Item");

String updatedSavedItems =  savedItems.replaceAll("rate":10//.370681//}", "rate":10//.370681,"//$rowSelect":false,"//$rowState"://{"invalid":false,"dirty":false,"added":false//}");

vars.put("UPDATED", updatedSavedItems);
}

catch (Throwable ex) {
 log.error("Problem in Beanshell", ex);
 throw ex;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you look into *jmeter.log* file?

According to [String.replaceAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method documentation:

> Note that backslashes () and dollar signs ($) in the replacement string may cause the results to be different than if it were being treated as a literal replacement string; see [Matcher.replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String)). Use [Matcher.quoteReplacement(java.lang.String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement(java.lang.String)) to suppress the special meaning of these characters, if desired.

So you need to amend your replacement line and escape dollar signs with 2 backslashes like:

```
String updatedSavedItems = savedItem.replaceAll("rate\":10", " rate\":10.370681,\"\\$rowSelect\":false,\"\\$rowState\":\"invalid\":false,\"dirty\":false,\"added\":false}");
```

Demo:

[image: Beanshell Replace]

More information: https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell